# Prove $\frac{3^{2m+1}+1}{4}$ and $3^{2m+1}-1$ are coprime

Tags: number-theory

For a positive integer $m$, let $n=2m+1$.

Then how can I prove

$\gcd{(\frac{3^n+1}{4}, 3^n-1)}=1$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What can you say about $\gcd (3^n+1,3^n-1)$?

Answer (score 4):

First show that $\frac{3^{2m+1}}{4}$ is odd. To do it, observe that $3^{2m}=9^m\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, so $3^{2m+1}\equiv 3\pmod{8}$. It follows that $3^{2m+1}+1\equiv 4\pmod{8}$, and therefore $\frac{3^{2m+1}}{4}$ is odd.

So any common factor of our two numbers is odd.

Now assume that $d$ is a common divisor of our $2$ numbers. Then $d$ divides $3^{2m+1}+1$ and $d$ divides $3^{2m+1}-1$. It follows that $d$ divides their difference $2$. But we saw that $d$ is odd. It follows that $d=1$.

Comment: It should be $3^{2m+1}\mathbf{+1}\equiv 4$ (mod $8$).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

$$\begin{align*}\frac{3^{2m+1}+1}4&=dx\\{}\\3^{2m+1}-1&=dy\end{align*}\;\;\;\;\;\;,\;\;d,x,y\in\Bbb Z$$

then

$$\frac12=dx-\frac{dy}4=\frac d4\left(4x-y\right)\implies2=d(4x-y)\implies d=1\;\;\vee\;\;2$$

Show that it is impossible that $\,d=2\;$ ...